# How to implement sqlcipher to encrypt Ionic project

Tags: encryption, sqlite, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, sqlcipher

I would like to encrypt my database on Ionic project, because without encryption i can install the apk in any device and accesa to storage as root and I can get the .db file and imported to any sql editor like sqlbrowser after that I can see all my data and table structure !

So for that we must encrypt ouer database,

The main problem, many talk about the cordova plugin SQLCipher, but there is no tutoriel or following steps to implement on Ionic project, just you can found steps on Android or iOS..

Does that mean we can implement the database ecryption on native part of the Ionic project or what ? The solution it's not clear, or how it work !

Link for  [npm plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.peerio.cordova.plugin.sqlcipher)

This is my code for test :

```
.factory('NotesDataService', function($cordovaSQLite, $ionicPlatform) {
  var db, dbName = "noteDemo.db"

  function useWebSql() {
    db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", "Note database", 200000)
    console.info('Using webSql')
  }

  function useSqlLite() {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
      name: dbName
    })
    console.info('Using SQLITE')
  }

  function initDatabase() {
    $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_NOTE (id integer primary key, title, content)')
      .then(function(res) {

      }, onErrorQuery)
  }

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova) {
      useSqlLite()
    } else {
      useWebSql()
    }

    initDatabase()
  })

  function onErrorQuery(err) {
    console.error(err)
  }

  return {
    createNote: function(note) {
      return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'INSERT INTO T_NOTE (title, content) VALUES(?, ?)', [note.title, note.content])
    },
    updateNote: function(note) {
      return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'UPDATE T_NOTE set title = ?, content = ? where id = ?', [note.title, note.content, note.id])
    },
    getAll: function(callback) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM T_NOTE').then(function(results) {
          var data = []

          for (i = 0, max = results.rows.length; i < max; i++) {
            data.push(results.rows.item(i))
          }

          callback(data)
        }, onErrorQuery)
      })
    },

    deleteNote: function(id) {
      return $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'DELETE FROM T_NOTE where id = ?', [id])
    },

    getById: function(id, callback) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'SELECT * FROM T_NOTE where id = ?', [id]).then(function(results) {
          callback(results.rows.item(0))
        })
      })
    }
  }
})

// Even if I add the argument like that, didn 't work ;


db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({
  name: dbName,
  password: "secret2"
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Add plugin to your Ionic project.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-sqlcipher-adapter
```

Step 2: Add `sqlitePlugin`.

```
function useWebSql() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'dbName.db', key: 'Enter key that you want', location: 'default'});
  //db = window.openDatabase(dbName, "1.0", "Note database", 200000)
  console.info('Using webSql')
}

function useSqlLite() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'dbName.db', key: 'Enter key that you want', location: 'default'});
  console.info('Using SQLITE')
}

function initDatabase(){
  //$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_NOTE (id integer primary key, title, content)')
    //.then(function(res){

   // }, onErrorQuery)

   db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T_NOTE (id integer primary key, title, content)',function(tx,results){},onErrorQuery);

        });
}

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
  if(window.cordova){
    useSqlLite()
  } else {
    useWebSql()
  }

  initDatabase()
})

function onErrorQuery(err){
  console.error(err)
}
```

Comment: How to use in ionic3/4/5 ?